# Angular how to pass data to nested route component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular Router and have the following nested route(s):

```
{
    path: 'resource/:id',
    component: ResourceComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'general',
        component: ResourceGeneralComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'background',
        component: ResourceBackgroundComponent
      }
    ]
}
```

`ResourceComponent` fetches a resource from a REST-API and contains a `<router-outlet>` in which the other components are rendered. The child route components should display different sections of the fetched data. I can get my data into the child components when i click on the corresponding link, using `history.state`. This however does not work when navigating to `url/resource/1/general`, because `ResourceGeneralComponent` does not have the required data from `ResourceComponent`.

I am passing the resource in the state through the link like this. Like i said clicking the link works fine.

```
<a routerLink="general" [state]="{resource: resource}" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link">General</a>
```

How do i get the resource into the child components so that it works without using `history.state`? I tried subscribing to an observable in the service that both the parent and child components share but the function passed to subscribe in child does not get called (probably because parent fires the observable event before child is rendered).

How do i pass data to the child components correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ReplaySubject](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/replaysubject-behaviorsubject-asyncsubject-in-angular/#replaysubject), this will replay any number of old values to new subscribers when they first subscribe.

Using a `ReplaySubject` with a `bufferSize` of `1` will replay the last/current value to new subscribers. That should be sufficient in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a property bag service with Subject or BehaviourSubject in it as properties.
Ive been through similar path and what i did is created a service with some properties in it.
I created the properties as BehaviourSubject so that i can subscribe to it and get notified when any change happens.

Comment: Sounds good but how do i solve the problem that the resource gets fetched in the main component first, and so the child is not rendered and hence can not receive the notification when the resource gets set? Do i delay the sending of the update in the main component or something?

Comment: if you are using observables and Subject you can solve the issue.and from the child subscribe for the property.